# How to apply inner padding without going off the area

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="divInnerFirst">
    <div id="divTitleHeaderUC">
        <span id="spanTitleHeaderUC">Urgent Care Wait Time</span>
    </div>
    <div id="divSubTitleUC">
            <div id="smallText" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; color: #000000; text-align: center;">If you are experiencing a life-threatening emergency, call 911 or go to your nearest emergency room. Do not go to the urgent care center.<br>Estimated wait times are provided for general information only, may change at any time, and may not reflect your actual wait time once you arrive.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#divTitleHeaderUC {
    width: 265px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(245, 159, 36, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}
#divSubTitleUC {
    width: 265px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #F59F24 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #F59F24 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #F59F24 0px 2px 3px;
    position: relative;
}
#spanTitleHeaderUC {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'blackjarregular';
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #F59F24;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the texts are going too much to the left and right which is making it hard to read. How can I apply an inner padding so that the text aren't too much to the left and right?
I tried adding padding to the `DIV` but it stretches out the `divSubTitleUC`.

Adding margin gives the following look:

[image]

Comment: Give it `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: I think you have problems with padding because of your absolute positioning. Try working on that width:100%

Comment: I added margin and padding and the text goes off the white box

Comment: Found a fix, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away the width, but instead, give it:

```
left:0;
right:0;
```

then

```
padding:0 10px;
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FrAaQ/)

The `left` and `right` 'stretch' the element to try and touch both sides of the parent container. Since the container is `position:relative;` it will never try and break out of the parent's boundaries.

Comment: I updated my question with what it looks like now. As you can see the text are outside to the right :/. `smallText` is in a stylesheet but I also have a inline specific style as well.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out high the DIV is so I can put another on above it?

Comment: How high it is? Not without using javascript.

Comment: And how would I position it above?

Comment: Ask this as another question as it's easier to write then and you will get loads of other answers too, not just from me :) @user3326071

Comment: Unless there's a reason to use absolute positioning, then take it out. You have about 2x as much CSS and markup as it appears you need (without knowing your exact requirements). And if you want a `div` above it, take off your positioning and let the DOM work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/gmE9M/

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez Would you be kind enough to mke a jsfiddle with my exact code? I want to add the text on the bottom as shown above and from `top:0` to the text top position I want to display something else (another `DIV` maybe)

Comment: @user3326071 - is there a reason to use absolute positioning here? It might help if you explained exactly what you are wanting to achieve, as otherwise the amended fiddle I linked to would appear to do what you want.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez What position do I have to use? I went with absolute so I can align it to the bottom of the `divSubTitleUC`

Answer (score 1):

You could add the padding as a percentage and reduce the width like

```
<div id="smallText" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 80%; padding: 0 10%; color: #000000; text-align: center;">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the absolute positioning and the width and give it just padding instead.

Like so:

```
div id="smallText" style="color: #000000; text-align: center;">

#smallText{
padding: 50px 10px;
padding-bottom:0;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/DrUx8/

Answer (score 1):

[**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3WkM/) Instead of using `position:absolute;`, use the following properties and your problem will be fixed.

```
#divSubTitleUC {
     display: table;
}

#smallText {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;  
}
```

Comment: UPVOTE for the answer which is also an option.

Comment: If you want to position it above, just do `vertical-align: top;` and boom. You can use `width` as well if you are going with this.